# What is the difference between « exprimer » and « s'exprimer »?

Tags: grammaire, choix-de-mot

How can I decide whether to choose *exprimer* or *s'exprimer* when writing sentences like « Elle veut que tu élèves ta voix pour que tu puisses mieux exprimer/t'exprimer ton argument » or « J'ai écrit un livre qui exprime/s'exprime la souffrance des Harkis »?

Comment: to express something and express oneself parallels the French. [que tu élève **la voix**]

Comment: @Lambie _parallel_, and not _parallels_ et "tu élève**s**"

Comment: @LPH Yes, élèves with an s. Thanks. In English two things like that can be viewed as one thing so the verb would take the s.

Comment: @Lambie I am very doubful that this construction could be a case of single subject or of coordinative apposition; I see in it a plain case of coordination with two subjects. Each of "to express something" and "to express oneself " parallel "XXX" (I don't understand what you mean by this parallel, but that is another problem). Do they both have to be implied for a parallel to result?

Comment: @LPH Spelling it out: **s'exprimer** is to **express oneself** as **exprimer** is to **express**. The uses in French parallel the uses in English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- ***S'exprimer*** means to express oneself, for example by speaking.
- ***Exprimer*** means to *express (something)*, to show.

In both of your examples, something is expressed so only *exprimer* makes sense. I guess you can't say in English *I want you to express yourself your point* or if you can, the meaning is not the expected one. Same with French.

> *Elle veut que tu élèves ta voix pour que tu puisses mieux **exprimer** ton argument.*

> *J'ai écrit un livre qui **exprime** la souffrance des Harkis.*

The reflexive form *s'exprimer* can be used that way:

> *Elle veut qu'on te donne la parole pour que tu puisses **t'exprimer**.*

That said, *exprimer son argument* is rare and *exprimer la souffrance* is literary.

I'd probably rather use ***exposer*** in the first sentence and ***décrire***, ***montrer*** or ***témoigner de*** in the second one.